# PHP Create a new ZIP from memory

Tags: php, zip

I have some textstrings in memory and want to create a simple ZIP from it.
Do I have to create a textfile and store it on the server first or can I create a ZIP directly from memory and store it finally. This would save time and action.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfromstring.php

Comment: I am pretty sure that manual is not closed today... http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfromstring.php

Comment: Hi guys -  I was reading the manual. Obviously must have overread this doe to a lot of ZIP SO answers relating to add files from disk. Thanks to people downvoting, very tolerant !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [addFromString()](http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfromstring.php) from ZipArchive.

Example very much alike the one from manual:

```
<?php
    $content = 'My content in Memory';

    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $res = $zip->open('archive.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE);
    if ($res === TRUE) {
        $zip->addFromString('file.txt', $content);
        $zip->close();
    } else {
       echo 'Error: Zip couldn\'t be created.';
    }
?>
```

Comment: @Ben : Did you find another solution or did this respond to your question?

Comment: I use and accept your answer. Works perfect. Thanks